# UseBrowserLink() causes Response.HasStarted to be set later in the Request cycle, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, browser-link

### A Interesting Observation

In Asp.Net Core the `HttpContext.Response.HasStarted` property indicates whether the response has startedor not.  Once it has started, you can not change the response since some of the bytes have already been sent to the browser.

I have observed what looks like strange behavior to me, where the inclusion of `UseBrowserLink()` in the Startup.cs `Configure` method causes the response to start later than it otherwise would.

Since it's common to use BrowserLink in dev but not in production, this means that the timing of `HttpContext.Response.HasStarted` is different for dev vs production, which is not ideal.

Example:

I just used the basic MVC template, to start with, I tried both the one for Asp.Net Core 2.2 and 3.1 and they both exhibit this behavior.  I will show the code below for 3.1 since it's the newer of the two.

#### Index.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pretty Basic Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

#### HomeController.cs Action Method

```
 public IActionResult Index() {
     return View();
 }
```

#### Startup.cs Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //app.UseBrowserLink();//run code, then uncomment and run again

            app.Use(async (context, next) => {
                await next();

                string path = context.Request.Path.ToString();
                bool hasStarted = context.Response.HasStarted;
                int i = 1;     //SET BREAK POINT HERE
            });

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

If you set a breakpoint at the spot indicated and run this code, `hasStarted` will be `true`.  Then if you uncomment the `app.UseBrowserLink()` line, and run the code again stopping at the breakpoint you will see that `hasStarted` is now `false`.

What's up with that?  This means that if I was using browserlink in dev, I could think that I'm allowed to modify the response at this point, but then when the code runs in production without `app.UseBrowserLink()` any code that attempts to modify the response at this point will be unsuccessful.

Why does BrowserLink cause this behavior?  Actually I like that rendering starts later but I want the start point to be the same with or without BrowserLink.  How can I get the code to start rendering later even when `UserBrowserLink` is not called?

Comment: The [source](https://github.com/aspnet/BrowserLink/blob/master/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink/BrowserLinkMiddleWare.cs#L97) should help. It swaps out the body stream for its own, so that it can inject scripts after it's been built.

Comment: Thanks.  Yep, that explains alot.